# Changing wallpaper of walls in an Image

Tags: php, image-processing

I want to create a web app. like [this site](http://www.fotoservr.com/site-rasch/)

If you see this site, when i choose a wallpaper texture and set it on one the wall in Image, only the selected wall's wallpaper changing.and it's very interesting because all of shades on the selected wall not changed!
I want to create something like that with `php. which techniques should i learn?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to like it?
 the link http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel

you can use bootstrap2.